# Trouble Creating a Double Animation

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a flashing animation for a Text Block in WPF in the code behind. I know that the text block as the opacity property, yet this code cannot seem to find it. What am I doing wrong?

```
DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation
{
    From = 1,
    To = 0,
    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)),
    AutoReverse = true,
    RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
};
myTextBlock.BeginAnimation(Opacity, da);
```

In addition, I am trying to create a color animation. That doesn't seem to be working either:

```
ColorAnimation ca = new ColorAnimation
{
    From = Colors.Red,
    To = Colors.Black,
    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
    AutoReverse = true,
    RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
};
myTextBlock.Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, ca);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me. Did you set the background color to red, first? If not try setting the background color to red.

Comment: I didn't and it was sending a null pointer exception. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Animation is applied to `Property`, not to `Field`. Also it seem you use parent's Opacity, not the TextBlock.

Change `Opacity` to `UIElement.OpacityProperty`:

```
DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation
{
    From = 1,
    To = 0,
    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)),
    AutoReverse = true,
    RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
};
myTextBlock.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, da);
```

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer.  No reason to create a storyboard for this simple animation.

Comment: @Baggins Just edited. Pls check again. Use `Storyboard` is an expensive action, more heavy than this.

Answer (score 1):

```
         Storyboard sboard = new Storyboard();
         DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation
           {
             From = 1,
             To = 0,
             AutoReverse = true,
             RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
           };
           Storyboard.SetTarget(da, urButton);
           Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath((object)UIElement.OpacityProperty));
           sboard.Children.Add(animation);
           sboard.Start()
```

Comment: This works beautifully, thanks! I am confused though, why do you write Storyboard.SetTarget(da, urButton); rather than sboard.SetTarget(da, urButton);?

Comment: Just because I was using it long time ago I am a bit rusty about that. Good that it helps ;)